# Python namedtuple : How can I reuse variables used to create attributes in a namedtuple to get values from the namedtuple?

Tags: python, namedtuple

How can I use `colname_1` to get a value for an attribute `foo` of a namedtuple?

```
from collections import namedtuple

colname_1 = 'foo'
colname_2 = 'bar'

Farm = namedtuple('Farm', 'foo bar')
farm = Farm('apple', 'banana')

farm.foo  # OK
farm.colname_1  #  of course this doesn't work!
```

Comment: Same as any other class

Answer (score 0):

Use `getattr()`:

```
getattr(farm, colname_1) # 'apple'
```

From the [named tuple docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> To retrieve a field whose name is stored in a string, use the `getattr()` function

Alternately, although clunky, you can index into the `._fields` attribute:

```
farm[[i for i, f in enumerate(farm._fields) if f == colname_1][0]] # 'apple'
```